# Returning a Promise in a Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to observe for any writes at a given ref and delete the same after a given time delay( in this case 5 seconds). When I deploy the following cloud function, the function returns instantly( within 1 second) once I add a new node to the ref but all the console logs are being printed in proper order.

```
exports.monitorActiveSignals = functions.database.ref('/names/{pushId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
         const key = snapshot.key;
         console.log(key);
         return wait(5000, snapshot).then((snap) => {
         console.log("timer done")
         snap.ref.remove();
         return;
   })
 })

const wait = (time, snap) => new Promise((resolve) => {
console.log(time)
console.log("timer started");
setTimeout(resolve(snap), time);
});
```

Comment: Don't you mean to use setTimeout?  setInterval triggers repeatedly over time, which I'm sure you don't want here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `setInterval(resolve(snap), time)`, what you're doing is calling the resolve method **before** the timer starts.  Then, nothing happens after the timer fires, because `resolve(snap)` returns nothing - there is no function to execute.  Why don't you try something like this instead, in order to actually defer the execution of `resolve()` until the timer fires:

```
exports.monitorActiveSignals = functions.database.ref('/names/{pushId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const key = snapshot.key;
    console.log(key);
    return wait(5000, snapshot).then((snap) => {
        console.log("timer done")
        snapshot.ref.remove();
        return;
    })
})

const wait = (time, snap) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log(time)
    console.log("timer started");
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
});
```